# Is there a way to query Google like this with PHP?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I can make this work..

```
if ($content = file_get_contents("http://www.somerandomwebsite.com"))  {
echo $content;
}
```

but..  is there a way to do this?

```
if ($content = file_get_contents("site:somerandomwebsite.com"))  {
echo "Still Indexed!";
}
else {
echo "Google does not love you anymore";
}
```

Comment: what is that for? Don't you mean `http://google.com/?q="some+query+-site:somrandomwebsite.com"`?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to fetch a google results page with file_get_contents. Try curl() instead.

Comment: @Alex-Ackerman Actually you can. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this URL: http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asomerandomwebsite.com

But just checking if there is content is not enough, you will need to parse the actual HTML of the resulting page.

You would do better to implement this: http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/docs/ (although it depreciated, I have not found the replacement - anyone know what it is?)